# How to using an array, double each of the following values and print

Tags: arrays

Using an array, double each of the following values and print each result:

```
values = [1.1, 10, 4.55, 30004, 0.2]
```

Comment: You need to specify what language you are using, what you have tried (as code), what you expect and what you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation:

```
double[] array = {1.1, 10, 4.55, 30004, 0.2};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(array[i] * 2);
}
```

Output is:

```
2.2
20.0
9.1
60008.0
0.4
```